# Azure DSC Configuration from Runbooks

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

I have the following Workflow script as a Runbook on my Azure Automation account:

```
workflow Configure-VM
{
    $DSCConfigPath = "C:\DSCConfigs\TestConfiguration"
    inlinescript
    {
        Import-Module PSDesiredStateConfiguration
        Configuration TestConfiguration
        {
            Node "ak-testvm-001" {
                WindowsFeature IIS {
                    Ensure = "Present"
                    Name = "Web-Server"
                }
            }
        }

        Write-Output "INFO: Creating the DSC Configuration"
        TestConfiguration -NodeName "ak-testvm-001" -OutputPath $Using:DSCConfigPath

        Write-Output "INFO: Deploying DSC Configuration"
        Start-DscConfiguration -Path $Using:DSCConfigPath -Force -Wait -Verbose
        Write-Output "INFO: DSC Configuration Finished"

        Write-Output "INFO: END OF RUNBOOK"
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run this RunBook:

`Import-Module: The specified module 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration' was not loaded because it was not found in any module directory.`

How can I run a DSC Configuration from Azure Runbooks? Is it even possible or do I absolutely need to use the Windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell Desired State Configuration support was added to Azure Automation in limited preview in May. You can read more on how to manage DSC nodes using Azure Automation [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-dsc-overview/).